How can I daemonize a shell command?
In a shell script, I'm launching a long-running background process. After initialization, this process writes many lines of output. In my shell script, I'd like to continue with subsequent commands only after this process has initialized (and, therefore, begun writing output).
I drafted a shell function to do this, but it's not working as I had hoped.
daemonize() {
    fifo=`basename $0`.$$
    mkfifo $fifo
    $* >$fifo &
    ( head -1; cat & ) <$fifo
    rm $fifo
}

daemonize yes
sleep 3 && kill $! && wait

I'm hoping that the script will output many lines of yes output (for three seconds); however, I get a single line of output. It seems that when the subshell exits, cat is killed.
Is there a way to do what I'm hoping in shell? I'm pretty sure that a single C program with a fork after reading a single line of output would do exactly what I'm hoping.

Shells derived from ash and pdksh won't keep the read end of your pipe open for cat, you need to do it yourself. And pipes are not seekable, you'll lose data with head.
Instead of
( head -1; cat & ) <$fifo
rm $fifo

do
exec 3<"$fifo"
rm "$fifo"
IFS= read -r line <&3
printf '%s\n' "$line"
cat <&3 &
exec 3<&-

and it'll work on most shells.

Thank you, this definitely works! I'm still using head as originally. As described in its manual, head doesn't require seeking. Is there any reason we can't depend on this? Also, I'm a little surprised that this many commands are required. Why are the FIFO and new FD even needed if we're in a subshell? Couldn't the children just borrow stdin and stdout while they're executing?

@PatrickCoppock If its input is not seekable, head -n 1 is not required to leave the file offset at the beginning of the second line. If you tell me which head implementation you use (GNU, BSD, busybox, toybox, something else?) I can take a look and tell you if it's reliable.

Shells like dash and mksh won't let background commands inherit their parents' stdin when job control is disabled (e.g. when executing a script). You can try enabling job control with set -m but I doubt it'd work as smoothly as with bash or zsh.

Interesting. I'm trying to write POSIX-portable scripts, so I think I will move off of head. I'll check the POSIX standard regarding job control.

@PatrickCoppock See XCU 2.9.3.1 then, the relevant paragraph starts with If, and only if, job control is disabled ...
